# Where did I go wrong using u-substitution on this indefinite integral?

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to evaluate the indefinite integral $\int x^3e^{x^4}dx$

I used u-substitution for $u=x^4$ and then attempted to solve.  I'm not sure where I went wrong, but when I know I went wrong because I don't get the original integral when I differentiate my solution.

Here are my steps as best as I can copy them into latex:
$$
u=x^4\\
du=3x^3\rightarrow du=3x^3 dx\rightarrow dx=\frac{du}{3x^3}\\
\int x^3e^{x^4}dx\rightarrow \int x^3e^u\frac{du}{3x^3}\rightarrow \frac{1}{3}\int e^u du\\
F(x)=\frac{1}{3}e^u+C\rightarrow F(x)=\frac{1}{3}e^{x^4}
+C
$$

When I try to check my work, it's not right:
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{3}e^{x^4}\rightarrow f(x)=\frac{1}{3}e^{4x}\\
f'(x)=\frac{1}{3}\times 4e^{4x}\neq x^3e^{x^4}
$$

Comment: For starters, if $u=x^4$ then $du = 4x^3\,dx$, not $3x^3\,dx$. So, the error is in line 2.

Comment: If we write comments to correct the errors in the question and then all the errors are corrected by the person, what becomes of the question? I'm not sure why people on this site answer questions using the comment mechanism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your work is [mostly] fine.  You have an error in that $du = 4x^3 \, dx \neq 3x^3 \, dx$.  Correcting that will give you the correct answer.

Your checking of your work, however, has a major error in the algebra.

Specifically $$e^{x^4} \neq e^{4x}$$
Perhaps you mixed up $e^{x^4}$ with $(e^x)^4 = e^{4x}$, but these are not the same.  Just leave it as $e^{x^4}$ and use the chain rule. It'll check out.

Comment: The work is not fine, OP has $d/dx(x^4)=3x^3$ where it should say $4$.

Answer (score 0):

Here the 3 should have been 4:
$$u=x^4\\
du=\mathbf{4}x^3\;dx
$$

> When I try to check my work, it's not right:
> $$
> f(x)=\frac{1}{3}e^{x^4}\rightarrow f(x)=\frac{1}{3}e^{4x}\\
> f'(x)=\frac{1}{3}\times 4e^{4x}\neq x^3e^{x^4}
> $$

The 3/4 difference is explained by the above error.

It also looks like you've accidentally written $x^4$ as $4x$ in the exponent of $e$.

Comment: I don't see why this should be deleted. The other answer by Moehring did not contain the information in this answer when it was originally posted. Please note the comment I made under Moehring's answer, after which he edited it.